# SignalR with Redis backplane: How to query the existing SignalR groups of all servers?

Tags: .net, redis, signalr

There are multiple servers utilizing SignalR to publish real time updates to clients. The SignalR groups are dynamically created depending on what the clients are doing. The servers use Redis backplane to get the messages across to the other servers.

When publishing a message, a server needs to first find out what SignalR groups exist, and then determine which groups it should publish to. However, A single server can only see its own existing client groups.

The issue with the strategy of publishing to all groups that could possibly exists, is that this list would be in the 10's of thousands at least. SignalR won't try to publish to a group with no members, but the server will. This would create 100's of millions of server publish attempts instead of just 10's of thousands, per second.

How can a single server query all the existing SignalR groups, including the ones on the other servers?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) - There is no API for getting a group membership list or a list of groups.

However, you could run with a fixed list of group names. This would be used on all of the servers. You would just publish messages to each group name in the list.

SignalR will not try to publish to a group if that group has no members.

Caveat though, this approach is not dynamic unless you update/expand your "list" of group names as you grow.

Comment: Yes, it appears there is no API for it in SignalR or the Redis backplane. The issue with the strategy of publishing to all groups that could possibly exists, is that this list would be in the 10's of thousands at least. SignalR won't try to publish to a group with no members, but the server will. This would create 100's of millions of server publish attempts instead of just 10's of thousands, per second.

Comment: The issue it seems is where to construct a 'live' list that all your servers can access to determine which groups it should publish to. Any option it seems will come with some performance hit. You may just try some methods (storing in a db, file, etc and see what is acceptable.